# how can i create tab in java swing

Tags: java, swing

Hi how can I put this value inside tab

I what a tab which got 4 values create user update,delete,search

```
topPanel.setLayout(null);
nameLabel.setBounds(300, 30, 150, 20);
txtName.setBounds(350,30,150,20);
surnameLabel.setBounds(300, 65, 150, 20);
txtSurname.setBounds(350,65,150,20);
passwordLabel.setBounds(70, 220, 150, 20);
passwordField.setBounds(130, 160, 150, 20);  

topPanel.add(nameLabel);
topPanel.add(txtName);
topPanel.add(surnameLabel);
topPanel.add(txtSurname);
topPanel.add(passwordLabel);
topPanel.add(passwordField);
```

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), it's got all the information you need. And, once again, you should use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead of a null layout.

Comment: why `null layout` cannot be used ?

Answer (score 3):

create a `JTabbedPane`

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
```

and add tabs in that pane.

```
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1,
                   "Does nothing");
```

[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) provided by @LuxxMiner is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

> You can do it like this :

```
JTabbedPane tabbePane = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel  panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JTextField  field = new JTextField();
JButton  button = new JButton();


tabbedPane.addTab("tab1", panel1);

field.setText("Your text here");
panel2.add(field);

button.setText("Save");
panel2.add(button);

tabbePane.addTab("tab2", panel2);
```

Comment: Good answer (+1), just a few remarks: 1) Please take a look at the [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), class instances should not start with an uppercase letter. 2) It's not necessary to set the text of a JButton/JTextField seperately from the constructor. Take a look at the constructor summary of a class, in your case of the [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) and [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

Comment: I have this  ) how can I add this inside of first tab

Comment: how can I add value inside a tab I follow this http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/15-javax-swing/1752-how-to-make-tabbed-pane-using-swing.html I what to add my textitem and button inside